# SQL Creating sub categories as a column

Tags: sql

I would like to create a template table in SQL which has sub categories as a column.

This is an example of what I want my output to look like:

```
Id    Type 
id1   fruit
id1   veg
id2   fruit
id2   veg
```

And so forth. I have the list of all the ids I want to include in this table. I basically want to map the two sub categories (fruit and veg) to each id. The table will be used as a template for some joins further down the road.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide us any more information about your data model? I need more information to help you.

Comment: I added more information in the edit. Thanks.

Comment: What is the *input* data for that output? What is the table definition? Please [edit] your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). [edit] your question do **not** post code or additional information in comments

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?